# Decrypting an Affine Cipher with Modulus

Tags: cryptography

I'm trying to decrypt the ciphertext vczkh which I know was encoded using an affine cipher with the equation 7x + 8(mod 26). This makes my decryption function p = (c – b) * a^-1 (mod 26) where b = 8, a = 7, c = number corresponding with cipher character starting from 0, and p is the same for plaintext. Since I can't have a fraction I calculated that 11 is congruent to 7 making my function p = (c - 8) * 11. Running this for all five letters gives me NMFWP but I know the answer is supposed to be NOVEL. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "11 is congruent to 7"???

Comment: Is it not? 7 * 11 = 77 and 77 % 26 = 1. That means congruence right?

Comment: "$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $c$" means $a-b$ is a multiple of $c$. Is $11-7$ a multiple of 26?

Comment: 77 divided by 26 leaves a remainder 1?

Comment: Never mind it's 15

Comment: I know that, but do you understand why it's 15, and how to work out that it is 15?

Comment: 7 * 15 = 104. Since 4 * 26 = 105 that means that both 15 and 7 must equal 1 mod 26. Is that right?

Comment: $7\times15=104$? $4\times26=105$?? 15 equals 1 mod 26??? 7 equals 1 mod 26????

Comment: I got that backwards, 7 X 15 = 105, 4 x 26 = 104, 15 * 7 = 1 mod 26. 105/104 = 1 mod 26. Now that I know I'm stupid can you explain why this is working

Comment: You wanted $7^{-1}\bmod{26}$, which means you wanted $q$ such that $7q\equiv1\bmod{26}$, and as you now undeerstand, $q=15$ works in that congruence. So the only question I still have for you is, do you know how to come up with that 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$y = ax + b \pmod {26} = 7x + 8 \pmod {26}$$

The inverse operation is given by:

$$x = \dfrac 1a (y - b) \pmod {26} = \dfrac{1}{7}(y - 8) \pmod {26} = 15(y-8) \pmod{26}$$

We are looking for a [*modular inverse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) (see the discussion on the [*Extended Euclidean algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)) and you were slightly off on that. Try it using this [*online calculator*](http://planetcalc.com/3311/). You get:

$$\dfrac{1}{7} \pmod{26} = 7^{-1} \pmod{26} = 15 \pmod {26}$$

I think you can take it from here.

Comment: $11\times15=165=6\times26+9$.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson, just transcribed it wrong - corrected!